# Inserting concatenated values in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok, this is what I am trying to achieve:

My script below is supposed to gather values across three tables and insert them in TO TABLE B in sequence.

There are two columns that are being affected in TABLE B the INDXLONG AND DDLINE.

In The DDLINE row I am attempting to concatenate values from different fields and to store them as one.

My code is below. Please share any insights:

```
Declare
    @nRowCount int, 
    @Indxlong int,
    @hdrLOCAL char(255),   
    @CR char(255),   
    @BLDCHKDT DATETIME,
    @BLDCHTIME DATETIME,   
    @hdrline int,   
    @1strowline int,   
    @2ndrowline int,   
    @3rdrowline int,   
    @BWP char(255),   
    @CompAcc char(11),   
    @BankCode char(11), 
    @BranchNo char(11),   
    @PayDate datetime,   
    @Reference char(11), 
    @TotaAmt numeric(19,5)
    @CoName char(11),   
    @BeneficiaryAcc char(11),   
    @BenBankBranchCode char(11),   
    @Salary numeric (19,5),   
    @BeneficiaryName char(23),   
    @TransRef char(23),   
    @outer_c int


SELECT @CompAcc =DDCOIDEN,
       @BankCode =DDIMORIG,
       @BranchNo =DDIMDEST,
       @Reference =DDDESC10,
       @CoName =DDIMORNM
FROM TABLE A

Declare ACH SCROLL CURSOR FOR 

SELECT T762.DDINDNAM,
        T762.DDTRANUM,
        T762.DDACTNUM,
        T762.DDAMTDLR,
        T756.PAYDATE
        FROM STATS.dbo.TABLE C T762
        LEFT OUTER JOIN STATS.dbo.TABLE D T756 ON (
                T762.INDXLONG = T756.INDXLONG
                AND T756.INCLPYMT = 1
                )
        WHERE (T756.INCLPYMT = 1)
            AND (T762.DDAMTDLR <> 0)
FOR READ ONLY;

OPEN ACH;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
FETCH FROM ACH INTO @BeneficiaryName,@BenBankBranchCode,@BeneficiaryAcc,@Salary,@paydate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
         Select @TotaAmt =SUM(@Salary)
         set @hdrline =1
         set @1strowline =2
         set @2ndrowline =3
         set @3rdrowline =9
         SELECT @hdrLOCAL = DDLINE FROM TABLE E WHERE INDXLONG =1
         SELECT @CR = DDLINE FROM TABLE E WHERE INDXLONG =2
         SELECT @BWP = DDLINE FROM TABLE E WHERE INDXLONG =3

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE B (INDXLONG,DDLINE)
    VALUES (1,@hdrLOCAL + ',' + @CR + ',' )
    SELECT @@IDENTITY
END
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE B (INDXLONG,DDLINE)
    VALUES (2,@CompAcc + @BranchNo +','+ @BWP+ ',' + @PayDate +',' + @Reference + ','+@TotaAmt + ','+ @TransRef)
    SELECT @@IDENTITY
END

BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE B (INDXLONG,DDLINE)
VALUES (3,@BeneficiaryAcc + ',' + @BenBankBranchCode +','+ @BeneficiaryAcc+ ',' + @Salary +',' + @Reference + ','+@TotaAmt + ','+ @TransRef)
    SELECT @@IDENTITY
END
FETCH FROM ACH INTO @BeneficiaryName,@BenBankBranchCode,@BeneficiaryAcc,@Salary,@paydate
END

CLOSE ACH
DEALLOCATE ACH
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

This is the error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 69
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 74
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

This is the result I am aiming for:

```
INDXLONG    DDLINE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ----------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------
1           101001       029       1403200610A094101 AMEN  BANK          LOVE    
2           123456 111               34567   PPDSALARYPAYT140131140117   11234567 
3           63206623    0101962706200    0000062709000319614      ADAMS EVE
```

Comment: "string or binary data would be truncated" - your field in the DB is too small to store what you're trying to stuff into it, e.g. sticking a string that's 16 chars long into a varchar(15) field. As well, is something wrong with your caps lock key? It's generally considered rude to yell at the people you're asking for help...

Comment: How is table B defined?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US.

Comment: **Please don't do this!**  Concatenated data in a database column is **evil**! You will regret this move, I promise you.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your dates into varchars/nvarchars if you are going to concatenate them. For examples, @PayDate should be casted like this: cast(PayDate as varchar(20)). Or if you need the date in a specific format, use Convert.